# Get the greatest element for each group of result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following fields: `user_id, app_mod, profile, update_date`.
The first three fields can be duplicated (i.e. two rows could have `user_id, app_mod and profile` equals, but different `update_date`):

```
user_id   app_mod  profile update_date
560047    RI03290   22809   14-GEN-10  
560047    RI03290   22809   18-GEN-10
```

How can I get the one row with higher `update_date` in an Oracle environment?

```
560047    RI03290     22809   18-GEN-10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table really only has 4 columns

```
SELECT user_id, app_mod, profile, max(update_date)
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY user_id, app_mod, profile
```

If the table has other columns as well that you're not including and that will not be duplicated that you do want returned

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               rank() over (partition by user_id, app_mod, profile
                                order by update_date desc) rnk
          FROM table_name a)
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

The analytic function `rank` will assign multiple rows the same rank if there are ties (i.e. the two rows have the same `user_id`, `app_mod`, `profile`, and `update_date`).  You could use `row_number` instead which would arbitrarily break the tie.  But that would not generally be a repeatable process-- Oracle might pick one of the two rows today and another row tomorrow.  If you were looking for rows other than the most recent row, you might also look at `dense_rank` but that will behave identically to `rank` if you're just looking for the most recent row.